# Upgrading Yarn produces an interesting error message? Is this normal?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

```
> Verifying integrity...
gpg: Signature made Thu Aug 27 06:16:49 2020 CDT
gpg:                using RSA key 6D98490C6F1ACDDD448E45954F77679369475BAA
gpg: Good signature from "Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 72EC F46A 56B4 AD39 C907  BBB7 1646 B01B 86E5 0310
     Subkey fingerprint: 6D98 490C 6F1A CDDD 448E  4595 4F77 6793 6947 5BAA
> GPG signature looks good
```